# Flutter - Include private repo from bitbucket for codemagic build

Tags: flutter, bitbucket, codemagic

How would i include a private repo thats on bitbucket in my pubspec.yaml?

Locally with the code checked out we can add this to pubspec.yaml

```
  sp_utilities:
    path: ../../packages/sp-utilities
```

But this would fail if you build from a build server.

We tried adding it as follow to no avail

```
  sp_utilities:
    git:
      url: https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx-utilities.git
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Dart Documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages):

> Even if the package repo is private, if you can connect to the repo using SSH, then you can depend on the package by using the repo’s SSH URL:

So the lines in the Pubspec.yaml should be as follow:

```
dependencies:
  kittens:
    git: https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx-utilities.git
```

This however requires [setting up a SSH Key](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/) for the authentication.

These steps can vary a little according to your system, and specific instructions can be found on the link above, but the tasks roughly are the same:

- Creating a pair o SSH key files using the command `ssh-keygen`.
- Adding this files to the SSH-Agent so you don't have to type your password everytime. The command related to this is `ssh-add`.
- Log in to your Bitbucket account and add the public key file contents there. That option should be inside `Personal settings > Account Settings > SSH Keys`.
- Confirm the operation on your e-mail.

You can confirm you have made all the steps above correctly by trying to SSH directly to it:

`ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This makes sense. I don't see an option to add an SSH key to codemagic. Is it possible to include the username and password in the pubspec / url?

Comment: Information on that may be found [here](https://docs.codemagic.io/getting-started/adding-apps-from-custom-sources/#generating-a-key-pair-in-codemagic). Let me know if that solves your problem.